# Mobile First WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe not getting fired

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

While trying to subscribe new ios device to Mobile first push notification using hybrid application , function WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe not getting fired

any help ?

Comment: can you describe more how you are seeing this issue? what version of mfp is this? are you seeing an error in xcode? can you describe how you implemented push and what you did to produce this error?

Comment: i am using Mobile First Version 7.1 , i am using the same steps on this article http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_setting_up_push_notification_iOS.html

Comment: Any exceptions in the Xcode Console? Where are you testing this? preview? ios simulator? device? Are you sure your code enters said function?

Answer (score 0):

Please apply this sample and see if the same issue is occurring.

If you still cannot subscribe, please provide xcode logs.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-native-ios-applications/event-source-based-notifications-in-native-ios-applications/

Answer (score 0):

fixed , while checking native code , i found  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method is exits which override WL registration process

just i removed it and it is working ok with me